# Armadillo error with SuperLU on macOS Catalina

Tags: c++, armadillo, macos-catalina

I have been trying to run the following program using armadillo linear algebra library. With Sparse matrices, I need to install SUPERLU 4.3. I first installed SUPERLU 5.2, but since armadillo documentation says it only works with version 4.3, I installed SUPERLU 4.3.

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  SpMat_Test
//
//  Created by Arash Fahim on 1/28/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Arash Fahim. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;

int main() {
    // insert code here...
    sp_mat A = sprandu(2000, 2000, 0.01);
    vec B=ones<vec>(2000);
    vec x = spsolve(A, B);
    return 0;
}
```

Before adding SUPERLU, the program complies and generates

```
error: spsolve(): use of SuperLU must be enabled
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::logic_error: spsolve(): use of SuperLU must be enabled
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

But, after SUPERLU, the error message has changed to

```
$ g++ -g  main.cpp -larmadillo
In file included from main.cpp:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/armadillo:88:
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/include_superlu.hpp:95:12: error: '/supermatrix.h' file not found, did you mean 'supermatrix.h'?
  #include ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP(ARMA_SLU_SUPERMATRIX_H)
           ^
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:79:30: note: expanded from macro 'ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP'
#define ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP(x) <x>
                             ^
In file included from main.cpp:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/armadillo:88:
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/include_superlu.hpp:96:12: error: '/superlu_enum_consts.h' file not found, did you mean 'superlu_enum_consts.h'?
  #include ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP(ARMA_SLU_SUPERLU_ENUM_CONSTS_H)
           ^
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:79:30: note: expanded from macro 'ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP'
#define ARMA_INCFILE_WRAP(x) <x>
                             ^
2 errors generated.
```

I checked that both files '/superlu_enum_consts.h' and '/supermatrix.h' exist in the path that should be found by the compiler, I guess. 
I am too biginner to understand what is wrong.